# Can't log in to MineCraft?

Tags: minecraft

I'm not sure if this is the right place, but I can't log in to my minecraft!! I'm entering my user details and my CORRECT password and using my CORRECT password it thinks I'm NOT using the correct password!

Answer (score 1):

It happens sometimes when mojang amazon server have some troubles, I think the best thing to do is to wait.
You can check here http://help.mojang.com/ the mojang server statuses.

Answer (score -1):

Change it on the website. Someone could have changed it, or there is a broken button on your keyboard.